# How can I add CocoaPods to my PATH after installing it on macOS(M1 Chip) for Flutter development?

Tags: flutter, macos

I've installed CocoaPods following the instructions at https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation, but I'm still unable to access it. Any guidance on adding it to my PATH would be greatly appreciated. Here's the current status of my development environment:

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of code or errors. Text is preferred so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try something like this to install it:

```
brew install cocoapods
```

I installed CocoaPods on macOS (Intel Chip) with `brew` and it works. You need to install the package manager `brew` on [this site](https://brew.sh/index_zh-cn) first.

Comment: It workde perfectly with the brew installation.